# How to configure Android phone for minecraft connection to computer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port-forwarding

I have a Ubuntu computer on which I am running a minecraft server. This computer is connected via WLAN (wlan0) to my WLAN hotspot with IP4 adress `A.A.A.A` (<- this is the IP address shown with `ifconfig`).

The WLAN hotspot is a LG G3 Android phone, connected to a Swiss phone provider (Salt) via mobile data. The android's phone IP4 address to the 'outside world' is `B.B.B.B` (as determined by opening http://www.whatsmyip.org/ on the phone or the computer).

Then I installed the "Port Forwarder" app on the android phone, in order to have people connect to my minecraft server on port 25565. In the Port Forwarder app I added a service to forward TCP from 25565 to 25565. 
The Target IP is set to `A.A.A.A` (as determined by `ifconfig`, it is something like 192.168.43.164).
The public interface is set to `wlan0` (other choices are `lo` and `rmnet0`).

However, when someone tries to connect to the minecraft server on my laptop with the server name `B.B.B.B:25565`, connection fails.

How can I fix it? Maybe I used wrong settings? Or the mobile provider has some ports blocked?

Comment: Where'd you get the `b.b.b` name? Do you have a dynamic dns or anything set up?

Comment: `b.b.b` is not a name, it is the IP adress  indicated when I open the website http://www.whatsmyip.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a static IP for port-forwarding the computer. (I'm not sure how you do it on ubuntu)
When you configured one you go to the server properties and use that static IP (most of the times it begins with 192.168).
When you have your static IP port-forwarded you need to go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and get the IP displayed. Everbody needs to connect to that IP.

In server-properties:

```
server-ip:STATIC_IP
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using a static IP address? Why do I need that? Also,  when I go to 'whatismyip' from the computer, I do not get a '192.168', but my current 'wlan' address is 192.168.43.164 (denoted A.A.A.A in the question). I will update the question, but may not be able to test any suggestion until in 10 days or so...

Comment: The router 'resets' all of it's IP's sometimes. These IP's are the IP's used in your own network. You need to disable that by using a static IP. 
When computers connect to the internet (not on your local network) you use a different IP. That different IP is shown by http://www.whatsmyip.org. (C.C.C.C) Outside computers can only see this IP of yours, so a Local IP won't work.

Conclusion:
Port forward local ip (static) (A.A.A.A)
Other people need to connect to 'public' IP (http://whatsmyip.org) (C.C.C.C)

Comment: Can you please confirm the port is opened using link (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)?

Comment: @hasnieking: I know the IP adresses might change. Therefore the IP adresses I am using are the IP adresses right in that exact moment I am trying to do the port forwarding. I check and change my IP address EVERY time I am trying to use my phone's port forwarding. I do not expect it to be constant all the time. I adjust the adresses EVERY TIME I have made the try to connect. Hope this is more clear now...

Comment: @tamadite: After I start the port forwarding on my phone on port 25565 and use the tool you suggested, and use the IP address indicated in the tool itself, the tool replies that the port is closed. Independent if a minecraft server instance is running or not.

Comment: Ok, then to be sure your ISP (Salt) is not blocking that port on their network you could either call them and ask or try to see if your phone (IP) is getting hits on that port. I'm not into Android so I can't help you there. If you get hits on that port then something is wrongly configured on your port forwarding.

Comment: And how could I dod that? Is there an app for android with which I can monitor which ports I get hit? I did a search but nothing came up...